# Angular Universal FULL SSR + Router not doing Http calls

Tags: angular

I'm actually trying NG Universal but when running the example code from : https://angular.io/guide/universal

https://angular.io/generated/zips/universal/universal.zip

I try to check how is that a full SSR app ... Each time the router call a new url when clicking on a router link the app don't seem to send a request to the express server to get the new html.

How is it working and is there a way to get full SSR with Angular Universal ?

Let's say that when i'm going from : /dashboard to /heroes to /heroes/:idEach time the router go from one point to another, I want the server to do all the api calls etc ... render the page and THEN send the HTML of the rendered page.

Why ?

To avoid the app in the browser to send any api request directly to our API's .

To be able to log on the server the actions of the user instead of being able to log only the first page load

Comment: You’re asking for two things here. Your first ‘issue’ isn’t an actual issue, at least not for search engines for example. Second issue, you don’t want to have your database/API online? You can consider prerendering (universal supports this) or you can consider something like scully.io

Comment: how do prerender work with, let's say an authenticated app ? 

To be clear, I'm expected to build an angular SSR app that hide the api calls for an authenticated application. 

The database and api will not be online so I need the server to do all the calls , even after the user is authenticated...

Comment: Hmm.. that’s not really how it works.. to authenticate you’ll have to communicate from the browser to a server.. but on your ‘server’ (looking at the SSR part) you just have the same app again..? Sounds like a strange requirement.. you need a proxy, not SSR..?

Comment: I think they imagine SSR as how something like PHP work, serving the page compiled etc ... 

They don't want to expose their api but increase the perfs with SSR + for the SEO. 

Pre rendering can work but only for not dynamic content ( like a blog with fixed url with content got from something like prismic or something ) 
It cannot work IMO for something more dynamic like the admin panel of a website where your content is dependent of your role. 

Wwhat they want is to have the same behaviour than for a php app for the admin panel of an angular website. So they want SSR on that part ...

Comment: Do that make sense ?

Comment: It’s not clear how they would envision the architecture for that.. especially not the auth part..